# Adobe Illustrator CC 2014 image problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have many .ai images one of them viewed me - Can’t open the illustration. The illustration contains an illegal operand. Guys, does someone heard or used any method to repair illustrator file?

Comment: Hello, there is no info that we can use to debug.  Revert to a backup-

Answer (score 1):

Either the file is corrupted or the file name has bad characters in it. Try renaming it to something like "fixed.ai".
Also try opening in something like vrc media player or irfanview, both robust, free image viewers, to see if it has recoverable graphic content.

Answer (score 1):

One possiblity: "Saved as Ai" in another application that has a misunderstanding what the genuine Adobe Illustrator wants. The file can still be importable back to that application.